# How to include many datapoints to plot in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to plot using chart.js, and in this I basically want to implement scatter line plots Here is the sample code taken from the documentation of [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts)

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [{
            x: -10,
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: 0,
            y: 10
        }, {
            x: 10,
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Here in this example there are only 3 data points, but in my case I have about 100 datapoints stored in 2 arrays namely xArray and yArray. I have tried using a for loop in the function but it was not working. Can someone help?

---

EDIT:
It had worked for me like this.
I made a new array and added the object ( of x coordinate and y coordinate ) into this array. Here is the code snippet.

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    var obj = {x:xFinal[i],y:yFinal[i]};
    c.push(obj);
}

// Note that here c is a variable declared as var c = [];
```

Comment: @Mussser I didn't concatenate, rather I made a new array and added the object (x and y coordinates) using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the arrays like so:

```
//var xArray = [{x: ?,y: ?}, {x: ?,y: ?}];
//var yArray = [{x: ?,y: ?}, {x: ?,y: ?}];
var concatenatedArray = xArray.concat(yArray);
```

Then, you can pass that in when you're invoking your chart like so:

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    datasets: concatenatedArray
},
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }]
    }
}
});
```

I hope this helps - keep me posted!